# Silverlight and database without any servers?

Tags: c#, sql, silverlight

My employer wants me to create a "webportal" that automates lots of work in the derpartment (<-was a typo, but decided to leave it there) I'm placed in.

The problem is: I work for a company with 40K employees and so many regulations it will makes you sick. Therefor it is absolutely impossible to get a server running for both websites and databases. I can't create one myself, because the computers on the corporate network have very limited rights and I just cant simply install what I want and there are key cards that require me to log on to my pc and I can't leave it there.

So yeah, servers are out of the question. My solution was something to maybe create something with flashbuilder and an SQLlite database, so no servers are required. I will put those on shared drives (that the IT department backs up every day). But since in my opinion flashbuilder is quite unstable and I am a great fan of C# and visual studio I thought that maybe silverlight could be my saviour. It's an object that can run without a server and I have tested a basic layout and that seems to work.

The question is: Can I use silverlight for this? Will it work in combination with [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/downloads/get/631318)? If it isn't possible please let me know why not and please help me find an other solution like a .exe application.

Comment: It should work. Give it a try and please let me know the result. I'm 100% sure that you can keep data in XML files with silverlight. No servers or service applications required. One thing to remember you have to publish your silverlight application in a server connected to your company's network.

Comment: @CemSönmez Thanks, I haven't had time to build a proof of concept yet, mainly because I still have to figure out the basic structure of a silverlight application. Anyway yeah the 'site' will be deployed at a share connected to the company network/vpn

Answer (score 2):

Well you can try creating an SQL Lite local DB that is inhouse to your project & then use Silverlight RIA services with it. I am not pretty sure, but theoretically it should work.